# How to pass a value to a running script?

Tags: php, sockets, laravel, download

I have a PHP script (I developed using Laravel) that will be used to download files stored in outside the webroot.
I now want to control the transfer speed for the ongoing download (e.g. do a usleep() inside the while(fread()) call based on some value that gets passed to the running script so that I can change the transfer speed externally in realtime) but I'm having trouble passing a value to a running php script.

```
while($buffer = fread($fp, 2048)) {
    print $buffer;
    flush();
    $this->bytes_transferred += strlen($buffer);
            usleep($this->transfer_delay);
}
```

So here's my question:
- how do I pass a value that can be intercepted inside the while() cycle?

I can think of a number of theoretical solutions but they all have problems:

**theoretical solution #1**- make the controller class have a class global variable (like $this->transfer_delay) to control speed

- register an event listener that will, somehow, change the value of that global variable, and the while cycle will then simply call usleep($this->transfer_delay)

**problem with theoretical solution #1** - I've tried to use events BUT my event did not seem to run.

Also, I suspect that events are ran in a different context and not in the method / class where they were instantiated.

**theoretical solution #2**- open a socket and listen for events!

- before entering the while cycle, open a socket and listen for events!

**problem with theoretical solution #2** - sockets require you to block waiting for new connections, so I wouldn't be able to transfer the file while waiting for a new connection

- maybe I can fork() the portion of the code that deals with accepting new connections and dealing with them? but then I won't be able to pass a value back to the parent, right? (or can I? using a signal handler of some sort?)

**theoretical solution #3** - pull events from a db every time I iterate through my cycle

- have the external process push a value to a db and have the while() cycle read from the DB on each iteration

**problem with theoretical solution #3** - it makes me feel DIRTY inside :o)

- I don't think it is good practice to hit a database multiple times per second to get a value in a "high speed while() cycle"

**theoretical solution #4** - use a named pipe

- create a fifo file and read from it on every iteration.

**problem with theoretical solution #4** - this actually seems to me like the BEST solution :o\

- I honestly can't think of anything superior to this but...there must be something else I can do?

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You can have the PHP read the speed from a text file and then you can change the speed while the script is running, as long as you close the file after each reads.

Comment: Use theory number three, but use an in-memory cache instead of a database. Academically this seems alright, practically, this seems like the wrong language for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly use sessions and then have a small PHP script change a value in the session variable. You will run into locking, where your while loop could be blocked by the file lock from the smaller PHP script until the the smaller PHP script releases its lock on the session file. You'll probably be closing and opening the session rapidly to prevent any locks like that from noticeably slowing down the transfer.

(This would prevent you from uploading multiple files at the same time from one session but that usually isn't an issue).

Comment: I haven't messed with sessions for a LONG time but I don't fully understand how I would use them for something like this?
In my case, two distinct processes will be controlling the download:
a) a user downloads a file so that PHP script will keep running until the download finishes
b) an external process gets a request to change the transfer speed for the ongoing transfer and, somehow, communicats with the PHP script that is already running and gives it a new instruction to follow

Comment: Can you point me to an example of how I could register a session variable and make it accessible to a completely external process? (e.g. the session is NOT shared by the same user who originated the download)

Comment: Oh, I did not know that the rate was being adjusted by a script that was not initiated by the user. In that case, you could possibly log the session id in a database (or even a text file) and have the script open up the session by looking up the id and start a session with that ID `session_id($ID)`. This is very similar to a named pipe where basically you have a file and a name/id for it and write to it for communication I guess (I didn't see that solution when I initially posted the answer).

Comment: Yes, I just thought about it and added it to the post :o)
I'm pursuing the fifo approach, though I'm having trouble with fopen and permissions on my server...anyway, that's a different problem.
That seems to be like the most reasonable solution so far.
What about events / message buffers like zeroMQ or stuff like that?

Comment: I have no experience with events or message buffers. Now that I think about it, I think memcached would be a good solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using memcached.
I don't know how great this solution is (as I feel it is a waste of resources to read from memcached every time I send a buffer OR even doing an if condition so that I only check the speed limit from memcached every X seconds or send()s) but...it works!